# How to save an uncertain amount of information in an android app?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, filestream, internal-storage

So, I am building an app that has the user input data such as a task manager would do. For example, the user will click on a button called "Create new event" and then my app leads them to a screen that has a bunch of questions such as "Date? Time? and name of event?". At the bottom of this screen is a "done" button. And when the user clicks this button, I need the app to save all the information that was entered by the user, and save it into a file with  the same name as the event. I need this file to be able to be accessed if needed and saved until the user decides to delete the event. So it's almost like making a calendar app that allows someone to enter an event and keeps that event on the calendar. Even if the app closes, the event should be on the calendar when the user opens the app again. I know I most likely will be using sharedPreferences, bundles, and files, but I don't know how to have my code make a unique file name every time an event is made.

Comment: A word of advice: set up an Event class with common fields that can be extended for corner cases, then write the fields to a SQLite3 database. Millions of little files on your mobile device will only lead to confusion and poor performance.

Comment: Use a database instead of a bunch of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure you need a sqlite (database) which on android can be used with Content Providers. This way you will get a nice performance and a easy-to-use, testing enviroment.

I'd recommend you checking this:

- [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)
- [Content Provider Basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)
- [Nice article to get you started](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Also, if you prefer, there are a lot of libraries to make it easier to use sqlite and content provider for android. [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) is the most popular, but there is also [RoBoCoP](https://github.com/mediarain/RoboCoP) and a generator for the schema and functions called [android-contentprovider-generator](https://github.com/BoD/android-contentprovider-generator/)

Using a database is also a nice approach because if you someday (or you already do) you decide to sync your db with your server, using ContentProvider is a [quite] simple task !

Hope it helps !

Comment: SQLite and Content Providers are two separate things. A `ContentProvider` can be connected any number of data sources.

Comment: It looks like this is the kind of information I need. Thank you for the links.

Comment: One question. I'm looking at these pages, and I notice that they seem complex. Is there any prior knowledge I should gain before trying to use an SQLite database. You could say I'm new to android app development, but I'm not sure how to measure that since I'm self taught.

Comment: It may seem scary and complex at the beginning, but I guarantee it's not, it's just a matter of studying and trying. I'd recommend you to try the vogella article, which is the simplest yet complete in the subject. Oh, and I'm a self taught myself too :)